# Google Api Asynch Callback Failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

i am getting a Requested content with:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    alert(xmlHttp.status);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

After the content is parsed into my new site via:

```
$Test = httpGet("www.content.com");
document.getElementById("div_content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div_content").innerHTML + $Test;
```

After this i will use google api asynch with callback but the callback function thorws an error

```
loadScriptFunc('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&callback=loadScript');
```

The error is: `window.loadScript is not a function`

I already did it with jquery $.get and this worked for me.

Edit:
The function is loaded like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('map_canvas')){
            loadScriptFunc('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&callback=loadScript');
          }
```

The function itself looks like:

```
function loadScriptFunc(url) 
{
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = url;
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

And the loadScript functions looks like that:

```
function loadScript() {
           var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
           var script = document.createElement('script');
           script.type = 'text/javascript';
           script.src = 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js';
           head.appendChild(script);
           bLoaded = true;
           window.setTimeout("activateMap()", 100);
         }
```

The loadScript Functions belongs to the template file of my map. This Code already worked for me with Jquerys- $.Get function same callback and so on. But i am not allowed to use jquery...

Edit2: 
I found something on the internet and i think i know whats the Problem.

> I have had success with jQuery.load() since it executes JavaScript code blocks and resources that are present inside fetched content. Sorry, no demo for this!

I guess i cant execute the code from the XMLHttpRequest, anyone knows another js method to get some content from a Url ??

Comment: loadScript is not a function.  jQuery's $.loadScript  is a function.  That's one of the things that jQuery does for you.

Comment: loadScript is one of my own functions into the view datei.

Comment: The error reporting says the function doesn't exist.  So maybe you're not loading the script where loadScript is defined.  Or maybe it's loaded later, so it doesn't exist yet, when needed.  Can you show the function, and how/where you load load it ... ?

Comment: Please explicitly add your function to the window object! window.callback = function(){...}

Comment: wich window Object ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I know what happened.
It's Google Maps that tells you it can't find loadScript().

So, you tell Google maps: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&**callback=loadScript**

Look what happens; I tell Google Maps to call initialize instead.

```
<style>
  #map_canvas {width: 400px; height: 400px;}
</style>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var my_position = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: my_position,
    zoom: 7
  });
}
function loadScriptFunc(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  head.appendChild(script);
}
if(document.getElementById('map_canvas')) {
  loadScriptFunc('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&callback=initialize');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I dont know how your code should help me solve my Problem, initiliza wont work for me aswell. Due to this my loadScript function is going to call activate Map a function which initialize the map.

Comment: Look, I'm telling you you cannot tell Google Maps "callback=loadScript" if loadScript does not exist.  This is what the error reporting is telling you.  Now, what's your question?

Comment: But loadScript exists, thats's what i'am tellung you. As i wrote the same Method worked for me already. Google accepts own functions as callback.

Comment: Show a document, where I can see where loadScript is, please.  Google Maps can't find it.  Is it a separate file?  Is it in script tags? ...

Comment: loadScript is a function 10 lines ahead of initilize in the  script tags. It's the templatefile of my map.

Comment: All the separate functions work.  The problem is the order in which things are loaded; the location of the function definitions.  And you're not showing these; loose clips don't tell that story.  What template?  How/where/when do you load it?

Comment: Dude, i cant show you my whole code... Also i think it's not that complicated its just a normal html datei with stuff like style for the map, the map div, and some custom shit about the marker. My code works like this if i open the tool just ower the browser liike: www.tool.com. The map and all marker are shown correctly. It's more a XMLHttpRequest problem i guess.